# No context on this server matched

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Here is my `index.jsp` code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Index JSP File</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/IndexController" method="get">
<table>
<tr><td>Enter Your Name :</td> <td><input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my `IndexController` Servlet code:

```
public class IndexController extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doProcess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String uname = request.getParameter("name");
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp?name="+uname);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doProcess(request, response);
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doProcess(request, response);
    }

}
```

Here is my `welcome.jsp` page code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<% String fname = request.getParameter("uname");%>
<h1>Welcome to JSP World,  <%=fname%></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this through the Java EE runtime, I got an `index.jsp` page, but after I entered a name and click submit I got the following error:

```
Error 404 - Not Found No context on this server matched or handled this request. Contexts known to this server are:  JSPExample(/JSPExample)
```

Comment: have you checked your servlet mapping configuration in Tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also change the line in welcome.jsp `<% String fname = request.getParameter("**uname**");%>` to `<% String fname = request.getParameter("**name**");%>`, since your parameter name is `name` `response.sendRedirect("**welcome.jsp?name="+uname);**` :)

Comment: I Changed '<% String fname = request.getParameter("uname");%>' to '<% String fname = request.getParameter("name");%>' facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

Edit web.xml and add the servlet mapping

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>IndexController</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>IndexController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>IndexController</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/IndexController</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse if you face with this problem, just create a new index file with another name. Then terminate last running server, and start a new server, run the new index.. file. I solve this problem wiht this way, at the end I delete the new index file and run my first index file.